# Edge on mobile device extremely reduces font-size when adding padding

Tags: html, css, mobile, microsoft-edge

I am trying to optimize a website for mobile devices and stumbled upon this strange issue in Edge on Windows 10 Mobile:

The font size gets dramatically reduced, when I use anything other than a border-/margin-/padding-less box with full width. See the following minimal example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Edge Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Without padding</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
        nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
        sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
        rebum.</p>
    </div>

    <div style="padding: 1em">
        <h1>With padding</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
        nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
        sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
        rebum.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is how it looks in edge on my mobile phone:

[image]

The same happens if I set margin or border instead of padding or set the width to anything other than `100%` or `auto`.

I guess this is a bug in edge (I am using version 25.10586.318.0)? Or is it for some strange reason intended behaviour?
Either way, is there a way to avoid the downscaling of the text without having to set fixed font sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these two lines in head section of your document:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: This indeed works, thanks! Can you explain a bit what exactly these tags are doing? Are there any side-effects for other browsers?

Comment: I just found out that the first one isn't necessary, setting `viewport` is enough.

Comment: No it'a basic need if you want to develop the responsive website, viewport is necessary.. but the first one is for some incompatibility with ie and edge browser which you may find in some tags although it's not necessary but it's a good practice. you can read more about viewport here http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp